# How do I print a single character multiple times on one line?

Tags: java

Here's what I need to do:

> In reverse order, print out the first num positive integers, with each integer being printed
> the number of times as its magnitude.

Basically, I'll use the number 9 as an example, I need to print 9 9's on one line, 8 8's on the second line, 7 7's, etc. all the way to 1.

I got it to print in reversed order but I don't know how I can print its magnitude.
Here's my code now:

```
static void printReverse(int n) {

for (int reverse = n; reverse = 1; reverse--) {
  System.out.println(reverse);
}

System.out.println(); // Leaves space between the outputs
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Use `print` instead of `println`. The `ln` stands for "line" and means "move to a new line after this".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print everything in 1 line then you need to change from println to print.
I added another for loop to print the numbers in one line and added the line break after this loop.

```
for (int reverse = 9; reverse >= 1; reverse--) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= reverse; i++)
    System.out.print(reverse);
  System.out.println();  // Line break after each number.
}
```

Output for the code above:

```
999999999
88888888
7777777
666666
55555
4444
333
22
1
```

I hope i understood clearly what you wanted.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that the "package system does not exist". What does this mean? I'm looking at the code you wrote and it seems like it would be fine.

Comment: I see what happened. I did a lowercase S instead of uppercase when I printed it.

Comment: @TylerP Did you write the "system" in lowercase? That is the only reason I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

This function accepts an integer and in reverse order, print out each integer the number of times as its magnitude. The first loop takes care of decrementing the number and the second loop resolves the magnitude. Each number is printed in a new line.

```
static void printReverse(int n) {
   for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
       for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
           System.out.print(i + " ");
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
}
```

This is the output:

```
n n n ... (n times)
n-1 n-1 ... (n-1 times)
n-2 n-2 ... (n-2 times)
...
3 3 3
2 2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run Java 11 there's a [method "repeat"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))  inherited from StringUtils I think :

```
static void printReverse(int n) {

for (int reverse = n; reverse = 1; reverse--) {
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(reverse).repeat(reverse));
}
```

Since there's a type conversion it's not faster than the double loop proposed but it's a one-liner

Answer (score 0):

Java has a repeat function to build copies of a source string:

```
String newString = "a".repeat(N);
assertEquals(EXPECTED_STRING, newString);
```

This allows us to repeat single characters, or multi-character strings:

```
String newString = "-->".repeat(5);
assertEquals("-->-->-->-->-->", newString);
```

reference: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-of-repeated-characters